# How to return an inout (reference) in a swift function?

Tags: arrays, swift, parameters, pass-by-reference

I'd like a function to return a reference of an array:

```
var a = [1, 2]
var b = [3, 4]

func arrayToPick(i:Int) -> [Int] {
    return i == 0 ? a : b
}

inout var d = arrayToPick(0)
d[0] = 6

println(a[0]) // 1
println(d[0]) // 6
```

I'm unable to return `&a` or `&b` in `arrayToPick` because those can't be casted to `[Int]`.

How to return a reference on `a` or `b` from a function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot return `inout` value. Because the compiler cannot guarantee the lifetime of the value.

You have **unsafe** way, like this:

```
var a = [1, 2]
var b = [3, 4]

func arrayToPick(i:Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int]> {
    if i == 0 {
        return withUnsafeMutablePointer(&a, { $0 })
    }
    else {
        return withUnsafeMutablePointer(&b, { $0 })
    }
}

var d = arrayToPick(0)
d.memory[0] = 6

println(a[0]) // -> 6
```

In this case, after `a` is deallocated, `d.memory` access may cause `BAD_ACCESS` error.

Or **safe** way, like this:

```
var a = [1, 2]
var b = [3, 4]

func withPickedArray(i:Int, f:(inout [Int]) -> Void) {
    i == 0 ? f(&a) : f(&b)
}

withPickedArray(0) { (inout picked:[Int]) in
    picked[0] = 6
}

println(a[0]) // -> 6
```

In this case, you can access the picked value only in the closure.

Comment: Why can't swift just do reference counting and guarantee the lifetime of the object where it is needed ?

Comment: @Droopycom Swift does that, but due to some strange reason, they chose `struct` to be always by value and `class` to be always by reference. For an even stranger reason - an array is a `struct`. Someone should have told them about the operator `&` and move semantics.

Comment: Swift 5 requires a slightly different function call format: withPickedArray(0) { ( picked:inout [Int]) in ......

Comment: The "safe" way is not exactly 100% safe. If by any chance you also change "a" or "b" inside the withPickedArray block, you'll get "Simultaneous accesses to 0xXYZ but modification requires exclusive access." runtime error. At least in swift 5.x. Can't see the reason why would one be accessing a/b there, but still, just to be aware.